# How can I check what day I made my repository private?

Tags: github, repository

I made a repository and in the beginning it was public, but later it was changed to private. How can I check what date I made it private? Because I don't remember and it is really important for me to figure out because I think someone might have found my code online and stole it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267307/github-api-find-when-repo-made-private

Comment: It does yes, unfortunately I don't how my code got out there, oh well.